# Pandas - Grouping and summing rows using a certain cell identifier

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm looking to do is take a table similar to the one below, identify all rows with the Type = 'Fee', and then add the total of that row to a row where some of the other columns match (So take the total from rows with Fee, find a row where the WEEK, STORE, and ID match, and add the total to that row). I should note that the row where Week, Store, and ID will match and it is NOT Type = Fee will be unique (only one of them) however there may be multiple fees that we want to group into it. As a single row example, the third row in the table below has the following:

- Week = 15
- Store = US1
- ID = T3400
- Total = 13

What I would look to do is find the row that matches those criteria, and add the sum. In this case, that would be row 1.

Within this data, there will be multiple Type = 'Fee' that I want to all collapse into this one row, the thing that I am struggling to do is preserve the Type that is not Fee the same.

I've given what the expected output would be below. In the expected output:

- Row 1 Total = 1098 = 200 (starting) + 13 (row 3 from input) + 885 (row 8 from input)
- Row 2 Total = 287 = 189 (starting) + 98 (row 5 from input)
- Row 3 Total = 15 (Did not change from input as there were no Fee where the ID matched)
- Row 4 Total =  581 = 146 (starting) + 435 (row 6 from input)
- Row 5 Total = 189 (Did not change because even though the Store and ID matches, it is from a different week)

As you can see, it will find the rows with Fee, match the other 3 columns, sum the total, and there are no more rows with 'Fee' in the entire dataset. Obviously this is only a small snippet of the data, in total it will have about 20,000 rows to go through.

Input:

| Week | Store | Type | ID | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | US1 | RE-G | T3400 | 200 |
| 15 | US4 | TO | T656 | 189 |
| 15 | US1 | Fee | T3400 | 13 |
| 16 | US4 | RD | T173 | 15 |
| 15 | US4 | Fee | T656 | 98 |
| 16 | US4 | Fee | T1121 | 435 |
| 17 | US4 | TO | T656 | 189 |
| 15 | US1 | Fee | T3400 | 885 |
| 16 | US4 | MX | T1121 | 146 |

Expected output:

| Week | Store | Type | ID | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | US1 | RE-G | T3400 | 1098 |
| 15 | US4 | TO | T656 | 287 |
| 16 | US4 | RD | T173 | 15 |
| 16 | US4 | MX | T1121 | 581 |
| 17 | US4 | TO | T656 | 189 |

Comment: We understand what you want to do, and what have you already done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to groupby week, store, and ID, and get the sum total.  You can also use `first` on Type after replacing Fee with nulls to get the correct type.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Week': [15, 15, 15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 15, 16],
 'Store': ['US1', 'US4', 'US1', 'US4', 'US4', 'US4', 'US4', 'US1', 'US4'],
 'Type': ['RE-G', 'TO', 'Fee', 'RD', 'Fee', 'Fee', 'TO', 'Fee', 'MX'],
 'ID': ['T3400',
  'T656',
  'T3400',
  'T173',
  'T656',
  'T1121',
  'T656',
  'T3400',
  'T1121'],
 'Total': [200, 189, 13, 15, 98, 435, 189, 885, 146]})


df['Type'].replace('Fee', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['Week','Store', 'ID'], as_index=False).agg({'Type':'first', 'Total':sum})

print(df)
```

Output

```
   Week Store     ID  Type  Total
0    15   US1  T3400  RE-G   1098
1    15   US4   T656    TO    287
2    16   US4  T1121    MX    581
3    16   US4   T173    RD     15
4    17   US4   T656    TO    189
```

Comment: There was a small error on my end, since we are receiving the input as a dataframe it has an index column, which prevents the groupby from working. I tested your functionality by giving it a csv version and manually deleting the index column and that worked, so i really appreciate that! Is there a clean way to run this ignoring the index column? We really don't care about the index itself, so the numbers can change if needed.

Comment: To clarify - its coming in as a dataframe and ideally leaving as a dataframe, but yeah error on my end and didn't let you know that there would be an index column, and if i delete that your script works fine. So any solution to this is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure why having an index column would matter, but if you can update your question to show the correct data format we can try again.